# Stack JButtons on top of each other in a JScrollPane

Tags: java, layout

I want to stack multiple JPanels on top of each other, to be scrollable in JScrollPane

[image]

I tried this:

**JFrame:**

```
setLayout(new BorderLayout());

JPanel boxListPanel = new JPanel();
        boxListPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(boxListPanel,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

boxListPanel.add(boxp1);
boxListPanel.add(boxp2);
boxListPanel.add(boxp3);

JScrollPane jscollPane = new JScrollPane(boxListPanel, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

add(jscollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

But the JButtons are streched like this:

[image]

When I use FlowLayout, the JButtons aren´t streched but they are ordered horizontaly.

**SOLUTION 1:**

```
DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();

box = new Box();
model.addElement(boxp);
box = new Box();
model.addElement(boxp);
box = new Box();
model.addElement(boxp);

JList<Box> boxes = new JList<>(model);
        boxes.setCellRenderer(new PanelRenderer());

JScrollPane jscollPane = new JScrollPane(boxes, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

jscollPane.setBounds(0, 0, 395, 600);
add(jscollPane);


class PanelRenderer implements ListCellRenderer {

    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        JButton renderer = (JButton) value;
//            renderer.setBackground(isSelected ? Color.red : list.getBackground());
        renderer.setBackground(list.getBackground());
        return renderer;
    }
}
```

**SOLUTION 2:**

```
setLayout(null);

int y_achis = 5;
        int x_achis = 5;
        int c_with = 380;
        int c_height = 65;
        int c_padding = 5;

...
box = new Box();
box.setBounds(x_achis, y_achis, c_with, c_height);
add(box)
y_achis += c_height + c_padding;

box = new Box();
box.setBounds(x_achis, y_achis, c_with, c_height);
add(box)
y_achis += c_height + c_padding;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the layout of the frame to absolutLayout !

Comment: There is no AbsolutLayout in Java ? Without any Layout for the JFrame it´s the same result.

Comment: you can user this import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.AbsolutePanel;

Comment: Ok, but is it possible witout a ~16MB lib? My app has ~1,7MB

Comment: com.google.gwt has olny 3.4 MB but I am sure you can find just the code for absoulute panel

Comment: I tried but it uses many other classes, and there are so smart solutions. See Main Topic